Understanding the "Expired Transaction" issue and what it means for an account listener
I have a web application which will listen to an account (utilizing @solana/web3.js) with Connection.onLogs, at the commitment levels 'processed', 'confirmed', and 'finalized'.
Reading over the Solana docs on Confirmations & Expiration, I want to be sure I understand what this means for a transaction monitor, vs. what it means for a transaction generator.
To my understanding, my concern is that it's possible that I may receive a log for a transaction at the 'processed' level, but then if it expires, I won't ever receive the 'confirmed' log.
But the article in general - is it more written to address concerns for the transaction creator (e.g. wallet) application?
I'm utilizing Solana Pay to generate a QR code for transfer requests with a Memo Program instruction. So I'm not creating the transaction - just providing that URL for a wallet to use - a wallet from the list of Solana Pay supporting wallets.
